# Calling Google cloud Vision API's on numpy matrices

Tags: python, numpy, google-api, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-functions

I'm using the Google Text detection API for performing OCR on images.

I've found that my OCR results are much better when I perform some pre-processing on the images using opencv.

My question is - how can I call the Google cloud Vision API's on images I have in memory as Numpy arrays? The official Google docs only show the vision api accepting an image in disk as the input.

I want to avoid unnecessary disk writes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way of providing the image to Google Cloud Vison API is as a [base64 encoded string](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/request#providing_the_image). The [quickstart example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/vision/cloud-client/quickstart/quickstart.py#L34-L43) uses the [Python client API](https://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/vision/gapic/v1/types.html#google.cloud.vision_v1.types.Image), which accepts a stream of bytes for the image content.

Instead of writing to file you can encode your OpenCV image `img` to a byte string you can directly pass to Cloud Vision API:

```
image = types.Image(content=cv2.imencode('.jpg', img)[1].tostring())
```

Comment: by `vision_client` do you mean `vision.types`? The `vision.ImageAnnotatorClient` doesn't have an `.image` method?

Comment: It used to, the API changed. Updated my answer.

Answer (score -1):

The currently supported mechanism allow you to use:

- A Google Cloud Storage (GCS) file that can contains the image data
- A local file that contains the image data

Alternately, you could use the REST API directly to base64 encode the image data and construct the REST request as given below:

[Making a Vision API Request](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/request)